# Subcategory of Isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory

There is a functor $\mathit{Iso} : \mathbf{Cat} \rightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ which identifies the subcategory of a category in which only the isomorphisms appear as arrows — i.e. it strips off any arrow that does not have an inverse.  This is because identities are isomorphisms, a composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism, and functors preserve isomorphism.

My question is this: can this functor be constructed out of more familiar categorical concepts?  For example, is it a limit of some diagram in $\mathbf{Cat}$?   Also, is there a standard name for this functor?

Comment: Presumably, this is just curiosity, so you have not seen it in nature yourself right?

Comment: @user67848, In nature?  I have seen it often (wearing another mask) when I am writing Haskell code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functor really takes values in the category of (small) groupoids $\text{Gpd}$. Once you've made that modification, it's the right adjoint to the inclusion functor $\text{Gpd} \to \text{Cat}$, which exhibits $\text{Gpd}$ as a [coreflective subcategory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) of $\text{Cat}$. It is sometimes called the [core](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core).